# Why Enterprise Library does not throw FaultException in WCF

Tags: wcf, exception, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, wcf-faults

I use WCF service hosted on IIS.
Also, I use fault contracts to send errors to the client (**FaultException<'T>**)
On the client side I catch **FaultException<'T>** to show some error to user.
If some unhandled exception being thrown on a server, WCF generates plain **FaultException**, 
so client catches it and shows user "Internal Server Error" message.

Then I began to use Enterprise Library 5.0 for WCF Exception Shielding, and met following issue. Using *FaultContractExceptionHandler* it is possible to carry all errors to the client, but in case of unhandled exception client receives **CommunicationException** instead of **FaultException**. Everything other works ok.

If I turned off exception handling policy (remove ExceptionShielding attibute), client catches **FaultExceptions** as expected.
Do you know what may be the reason?
Thanks.

PS: Here is a chain of inner exceptions:
CommunicationException -> WebException -> IOException -> SocketException
Message is "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server."

**Web.config**

```
<add name="ServiceException Policy">
    <exceptionTypes>
      <add name="ServiceLogicException" type="LopService.Contracts.ServiceLogicException, LopService.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.1725, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
        <exceptionHandlers>
          <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF.FaultContractExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            faultContractType="LopService.Contracts.ServiceLogicFaultContract, LopService.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.1725, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            name="Fault Contract Exception Handler" />
        </exceptionHandlers>
      </add>
    </exceptionTypes>
  </add>
```

**Service Class**

```
[ExceptionShielding("ServiceException Policy")]
public partial class LopSoapService
{...
```

**Operation Contract**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DataValidationFaultContract))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceLogicFaultContract))]
    int CreateUser(UserDto userDto, IEnumerable<ClaimRecordDto> claimRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Enterprise Library.  See this [workitem](http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/12026).